# What happened to this question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

The question [What is a whip stall?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/18859/what-is-a-whip-stall) just had some activity I've never seen before. It is showing on the home page saying that [Rick Bennett](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/users/67877/rick-bennett), an unregistered, 1-rep user with no questions or answers and no accounts on other sites, "modified" it. In the history, it says that Community protected it, at the same time that the home page sais Rick Bennett modified it; the history page says nothing about Rick Bennett. Neither the question nor its one answer has been edited by a user with the name Rick Bennett.

What happened to this question? Did "Rick Bennett" really do something with it? Why did Community protect it after seven years of inactivity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Jamiec said, that user added an answer, which is now deleted. With access to [moderator tools](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) (requires 10K reputation), the [question timeline](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/posts/18859/timeline) looks like this:

[image: Timeline]

As you can see, there are already **4 deleted answers** for this question. As the question seems to attract low quality answers, it was automatically protected by the Community Bot (see also [What is a “protected” or "highly active" question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52764/what-is-a-protected-or-highly-active-question) on Meta).

Answer (score 4):

That user added a non-answer, which was deleted by a moderator. With 10K rep you will be able to see deleted answers.

Unfortunately, the StackExchange system still shows you that *something* was done on that question, by that user, on the homepage.